# Save current user's message list in parse with swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfrelation

I use parse for my app. I want to let user able to type messages that they want to send via textField and save it to that user's messages column in parse with `PFRelation` via save button in view controller and the messages will be saved as an array and show it in `tableView`.

The problem is I don't know how to add text in textfield to an array and save it to parse.

Any help is appreciated and let me know if you need any additional information!

**UPDATE:**

[These](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xp48v3yn0l2hje/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-03%20at%202.10.13%20PM.png?dl=0) are screenshots of my parse's class "User"

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pd8mt8sf35u1m0v/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-03%20at%202.10.55%20PM.png?dl=0) is my current user's friend list inside "Friends" column

I've not yet create Messages column because when run `relationForKey` code in Xcode it will automatically create for me

**UPDATE 2:**

This is my code:

```
@IBAction func addMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
    var newMessage = addMessageText.text
    let message = PFObject(className: "Messages")
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
    message["messageTextColumn"] = newMessage



    message.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {


            println("added to Message Class")
            query.whereKey("messageTextColumn", equalTo: newMessage)
            query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{(object:PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    let relation = PFUser.currentUser().relationForKey("Messages")
                    var addMessageWithObject = object
                    if addMessageWithObject != nil {
                        relation.addObject(addMessageWithObject)
                        println("Added with getFirstObject")
                    }
                    else{
                        println("Error Added with getFirstObject")
                    }
                }
            }



        } else {
            println("added to Message class Error")
        }
    }
    }
```

I save new message to the array first and then I save it with saveInBackgroundWithBlock.. and inside I query that message to add it to relation.

The messages that I've added appear on Messages class table but not in that user's relation but it shows log

```
"added to Message Class" and "Added with getFirstObject"
```

Which means that my code execute exactly like it should be. Probably about the method?
**UPDATE 3** this is the object println

```
<Messages: 0x7fd4484f75f0, objectId: LFXoSaHfQl, localId: (null)> {
ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd4484d2e70>";
messageTextColumn = 9;
```

}

**UPDATE 4** 
this is my code

```
@IBAction func addMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
    var newMessage = addMessageText.text
    let message = PFObject(className: "Messages")
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
    message["messageTextColumn"] = newMessage

        message.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {


                println("added to Message Class")
                query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{(object:PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        var addMessageWithObject = object
                        if addMessageWithObject != nil {
                            user.saveInBackground()
                            println("Added with getFirstObject")
                        }
                        else{
                            println("Error Added with getFirstObject")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

user column is (undefined) as in screenshot here 
[image: Messages class table]
and the error log `can't add non pointer to relation`  is back

how do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What is your Parse DB structure to store the messages for a user? It would also be nice to se what you have tried for this.

Comment: I tried saveInBackgroundWithBlock but then I realize that it won't work so right now, It's practically empty swift file

Comment: Okay. Would you be able to show the DB structure? The fields?

Comment: My parse db structure screenshot right? sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Just want to see how the message will be stored.

Comment: in parse website or in my Xcode? Well I want to store them in my current user's Message relation in parse User class.

Comment: I've added it to my question.

Comment: This was a good video on Parse relations. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x70G_LPlW60

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do:

1. Manually create your `Message` table on Parse
2. Add a `messages` column to your user table of type `Relation` with Target Class as your `Message` table.
3. In your code, in your buttons trigger:

   ```
   // Get the message text from your textField
   let messageText = textField.text

   // Create your new Message object
   let newMessage = PFObject(className: "Message")
   // ... Add your data to your new message object
   newMessage["messageTextColumn"] = messageText

   newMessage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
       (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
       if (success) {
           // Add the new message to the user's relation
           let relation = yourUser.relationForKey("messagesColumnName")
           relation.addObject(newMessage)

           // Save the user object
           yourUser.saveInBackground()
       } else {
           // There was a problem, check error.description
       }
   }
   ```

[Here's a link to Parse's Relation reference](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#relations).

**UPDATE:**

Missing code to save your user object.

```
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{(object:PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let relation = PFUser.currentUser().relationForKey("Messages")
                var addMessageWithObject = object
                if addMessageWithObject != nil {
                    relation.addObject(addMessageWithObject)

                    PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackground()

                    println("Added with getFirstObject")
                }
                else{
                    println("Error Added with getFirstObject")
                }
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Messages without PFRelation:

1. Add a column (let's say `user`) of type Pointer with Target Class as _User to the `Messages` table to identify each message by their user.
2. Saving new messages: Save the new message object like above (just without adding the relation and it'e related code):

   ```
   @IBAction func addMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
       var newMessage = addMessageText.text

       let message = PFObject(className: "Messages")
       message["messageTextColumn"] = newMessage
       message["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()

       message.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
           if (success) {
               println("added to Message Class")
           } else {
               // Error saving message
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Querying the messages for a user: You can query using the current user as a constraint so no matter which device a particular switches to, he/she will get only his messages.

   ```
   var query = PFQuery(className:"Messages")
   query.whereKey("user", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser())
   query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82222/discussion-on-answer-by-kriz-save-current-users-message-list-in-parse-with-swif).

Comment: Are you sure your user object is authenticated on Parse?